# Select rows with same value on other field

Tags: php, sql, symfony

So, i have an entity (i'm using symfony) `Participant`.

In this entity i have : `id` `account_id` `conversation_id`

`account_id` is the `User` object, and `conversation_id` is the `Conversation` object, both are foreign keys.

I need to know if, for start, user1 and user2 are in the same conversation.
And after i need to know if user1, user2.... userN are in the same conversation.

I don't know how to do that simply with a query ? Thanks !

Comment: You need to get the users list who are in a specific conversation, right?

Comment: I need to know if two or more users are in the same conversation. i haven't the conversation object, i need to know that for create a new conversation or use an existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   n.*
FROM
   Participant n JOIN
(
  SELECT 
      t.conversation_id
  FROM
      Participant t
  WHERE 
          t.user_id = 'user1' 
      AND 
          t.conversation_id = (SELECT conversation_id FROM Participant WHERE user_id = 'user2' AND conversation_id = t.conversation_id)
) m on m.conversation_id = n.conversation_id
```

Comment: I don't understand... where is my second user ?

Comment: I have this error : ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression, because (SELECT conversation_id FROM Participant WHERE user_id = 'user2') can return a lots of results i think

Comment: @Clément Andraud : Check now.I didn't take in consideration that user2 could have more than one dialogue :)

Comment: I need to translate for symfony now... ^^